# Simple javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need: `www.mydomain.com:1235` form the `text` var below:

```
var text = 'http://www.mydomain.com:1235/;image.jpg';

alert(text.match(/\/[^]+\//));

output is: //www.mydomain.com:1235/
```

How do I exclude the delimiters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use parens to group what you want to match.  Then, the call to `.match()` will let you use indexers.  Index 0 is the whole string match, and index 1 is the first paren grouping.

```
var text = 'http://www.mydomain.com:1235/;image.jpg';
alert(text.match(/\/([^\/]+)\//)[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a regex, but you could do this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/nTmv9/

```
text = text.split('http://')[1].split('/')[0];
```

or with a regex:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/nTmv9/1/

```
text = text.match(/http:\/\/([^\/]+)\//)[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

This will capture the domain without the http or the url slugs.

```
https?:\/\/([^\/]+)\/
```

If you need help figuring out regex here is a great tool I use all of the time.

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for that link too, looks very helpful